# Getting infos about a specific queue in sidekiq

Tags: ruby, queue, sidekiq

If you run `stats = Sidekiq::Stats.new`, I get a lot of interesting data about my jobs :

```
  {:processed=>84063, :failed=>120, :scheduled_size=>0, :retry_size=>0, :dead_size=>7, :processes_size=>3, :default_queue_latency=>0, :workers_size=>0, :enqueued=>0}>
```

Im trying to get the same infos (number of processed jobs, failed...) but for a specific queue.
I dont see how to get this info from there :

```
https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/API#queue
```

For instance how do you get the number of jobs that were processed on a specific queue and my generally any info for a specific queue as in Stats

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sidekiq does not persist those numbers per queue.  You can construct them using the Statsd support in Sidekiq Pro, as it does tag each perform with the associated queue. https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Pro-Metrics#tags